# gpio get value of pin

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio

I'm trying to get the value of a single pin from an rc receiver (receiver info at bottom). What's the correct way to read the value coming in? Here's my existing code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

while True:
    print(GPIO.input(23))

GPIO.cleanup()
```

More info:

I have an RC receiver that controls servos / brushless motors. I've been having trouble finding a data sheet for it but an image of the receiver is below:

[image: rc receiver]

Comment: Have you identified a ground pin?  Not much point in reading a pin unless you also connect its ground to the Pi.  Have you confirmed that the range of voltages on the pin is Pi safe, i.e. between 0 and 3.3V?  If so the code will read the pin's level as high (>2) or low (<1),  The pull down is redundant.

Comment: I know the ground column is the furthest right in the photo. You can see a little diagram on the receiver just left of where you see "BAT". I just read on my multimeter for the throttle signal pin an ACmA range of 2.4(low) - to 3.74(high). FYI the Throttle is CH3 with left-right pin order of signal, hot, ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm affraid there is no "value" here that you can read easily with RPi.

http://www.mitchr.me/SS/batteriesRequired/RCcontrolTheory/

Long story short: you would have to measure the time between pulses, use interrupts and python will be not fast enough to do that. C code will be more suited.

GPIO interrupts, read here:

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=7509
http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=9207

And on electrical part of a problem. Those RC receivers works on 5V, GPIO is 3.3V. Voltage divider required.

Comment: I was planning on using C but it sounds like rpi still isn't the right tool for me. What if I plugged my analog pins into an arduino and then shipped the info off to rpi via digital? It might require some sort of "digital encapsulation" but it's doable ya?

Comment: They are not even "analog". What I would do is: use Arduino (or even better bare Atmega) to measure length of pulses and communicate with RPi via I2C. Arduino/Atmega would be I2C slave and RPi master

Comment: Starting with the arduino may be a good idea here as there is source code available.